# Making a list of sums of subsets of a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

We have a list say `list1 = [2, 1, 4]`

I made a 2d list called subl of the subsets of list1 with following code.

```py
def sub_lists(list1):
    sublist = [[]]
    for i in range(0, len(list1) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list1) + 1):
            sub = list1[i:j]
            sublist.append(sub)
    return sublist
```

The output I got is

```py
subl = sub_lists(list1) #[[], [2], [2, 1], [2, 1, 4], [1], [1, 4]]
```

Now I want to make an array of sums of the list elements present in in subl
I wrote following code but its not working correctly.

```py
sum = [];
for i in range(0, len(subl) - 1):
  l = len(subl[i])
  t = 0
  for j in range(0, l - 1):
    t = t + subl[i][j]
  sum.append(t)
print(sum)
```

The output I'm getting is

```
[0, 0, 2, 3, 0]
```

While the desired output should be

```
[0,2,3,7,1,5]
```

I guess there's something wrong in the second for loop. Please help!

Comment: Those aren't really the subsets, more like subsets of contiguous values

Comment: Change `for j in range(0, l-1):` to `for j in range(0, l):`

Comment: why appending list just add `sublist.append(sum(sub))`

Comment: You can also try, ```[sum(x) for x in subl]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason isn't working is because you are looping up to `i=len(subl)-2` and `j=l-2`, which makes that the last element isn't counted, so you can change both loops to `for i in range(0, len(subl)):` and `for j in range(0, l):`. Also, as a suggestion, don't use `sum` as a variable name because it's a built in function in python and it can yield errors. So, the corrected code will be:

```
list1 = [2, 1, 4]
def sub_lists(list1):
    sublist = [[]]
    for i in range(0, len(list1) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list1) + 1):
            sub = list1[i:j]
            sublist.append(sub)
    return sublist

subl=sub_lists(list1)
s=[];
for i in range(0, len(subl)):
    l=len(subl[i])
    t=0;
    for j in range(0, l):
        t=t+subl[i][j]
    s.append(t)
print(s)
```

---

As a suggestion, you could use `map` and `sum`

```
list1 = [2, 1, 4]
def sub_lists(list1):
    sublist = [[]]
    for i in range(0, len(list1) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list1) + 1):
            sub = list1[i:j]
            sublist.append(sub)
    return sublist

subl=sub_lists(list1)
s=list(map(sum, subl))
#same as [sum(l) for l in subl]
print(s)
```

Or just add the sum as @deadshot said, if your principal purpose is the sum of the sublists:

```
list1 = [2, 1, 4]
def sum_of_sublists(list1):
    sublist = [0]
    for i in range(0, len(list1) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list1) + 1):
            sub = list1[i:j]
            sublist.append(sum(sub))
    return sublist

print(sum_of_sublists(list1))
```

All outputs:

```
[0,2,3,7,1,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because your ranges are incorrect, use respectively `range(0, len(subl))` and `range(0, l)`

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
list1 = [2, 1, 4]
subl = sub_lists(list1)
```

You could just use list comprehension to find the sum of sub lists :

```py
ans = [int(np.sum(l)) for l in subl]
```

**Output :**

```
ans # prints [0, 2, 3, 7, 1, 5]
```